# How to Subtract Two Rows which Have One Matching Value in a Column

Tags: sql, postgresql, subtraction

I'm comparing sales for same week of different year. Like first week of 2010 and 2011. So with my query I get such results.

```
week|year|sales
1   |2010|5
1   |2011|10
2   |2010|7
2   |2011|13
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT
min(x.id) AS id,
week as week,
year,
COUNT(*) AS amount,
SUM(price_unit) AS price
FROM (
   SELECT
   so.id as id,
   DATE_PART('week',  so.date_order) AS week,
   DATE_PART('year',  so.date_order) AS year,
 sol.price_unit
 FROM 
sale_order AS so
INNER JOIN sale_order_line AS sol ON sol.order_id = so.id
WHERE so.date_order BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2011-12-31' 
) AS x
GROUP BY
week,
year
```

What I want to do, is to subtract same weeks of different years, to get the difference in sales. Like week2011-week2010 and results should look like that

```
week|year     |difference
 1  |2011-2010|5
 2  |2011-2010|6
```

I just don't have an idea how to subtract like that:)

Answer (score 1):

To get the difference between the two years, try this:

```
SELECT
week as week,
'2011-2010' as year,
sum(case calcyear when 2011 then 1 else -1 end) AS amount,
sum(case calcyear when 2011 then price_unit else -1*price_unit end) AS price
FROM (
   SELECT
   so.id as id,
   DATE_PART('week',  so.date_order) AS week,
   DATE_PART('year',  so.date_order) AS calcyear,
 sol.price_unit
 FROM 
sale_order AS so
INNER JOIN sale_order_line AS sol ON sol.order_id = so.id
WHERE so.date_order BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2011-12-31' 
) AS x
GROUP BY
week
```

Comment: If try this, i get an error "column "calcyear" does not exist". So it seems that my DB doesn't recognize such function? Is there an alternative to this?

Comment: @tatsuo, calcyear is an **amended** alias in the subquery (so that a string "year" can be displayed in the main query) - check that you have amended the subquery accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Now it subtracts the way I want.

Comment: Also I noticed one thing, that I always get the last week of the year (I mean of 2011), which hasn't come yet. Is this a bug in a function or it could be something wrong in my DB? Cause I get till 50 week, then don't get fifty first week, which I shouldn't get, but I get 52nd week.

Comment: You are including data from all of 2010, which should include data for weeks 50 onwards. Also, beware that the `week` date_part returns the **ISO** week (ISO week 1 does not necessarily start on the first day of the year) - you might be better off dividing date_part('doy') by 7.